# Python error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python, package

I'm totally new to Python and I know this question was asked many times, but unfortunately it seems that my situation is a bit different...
I have created a package (or so I think). The catalog tree is like this:

```
mydir
    lib   (__init__.py)
        mod1  (__init__.py, mod11.py)
```

In parenthesis there are files in the catalog. Both `__init__.py` files are zero length.

The file `mydir/lib/mod1/mod11.py` contains the following:

```py
def mod12():
    print "mod12"
```

Now, I run `python`, then `import lib`, which works OK, then `lib.mod11()` or `lib.mod12()`.

Either of the last two gives me the subject error message. Actually `dir(lib)` after Step 2 does not display `mod11` or `mod12` either.
It seems I'm missing something really simple.

(I'm using Python 2.6 in Ubuntu 10.10)

Thank you

Comment: The error message in the subject is incomplete. It may be helpful to post the full error message here in the body.

Answer (score 49):

When you `import lib`, you're importing the package. The only file to get evaluated and run in this case is the 0 byte `__init__.py` in the lib directory.

If you want access to your function, you can do something like this `from lib.mod1 import mod1` and then run the `mod12` function like so `mod1.mod12()`.

If you want to be able to access `mod1` when you import `lib`, you need to put an `import mod1` inside the `__init__.py` file inside the `lib` directory.

Comment: I tried to add `import mod1` in `lib/__init__.py`. When I `import lib`, I got an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod1'`.

Answer (score 32):

More accurately, your `mod1` and `lib` directories are not modules, they are packages. The file `mod11.py` is a module.

Python does not automatically import subpackages or modules. You have to explicitly do it, or "cheat" by adding import statements in the initializers.

```
>>> import lib
>>> dir(lib)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
>>> import lib.pkg1
>>> import lib.pkg1.mod11
>>> lib.pkg1.mod11.mod12()
mod12
```

An alternative is to use the `from` syntax to "pull" a module from a package into you scripts namespace.

```
>>> from lib.pkg1 import mod11
```

Then reference the function as simply `mod11.mod12()`.

Answer (score 6):

The way I would do it is to leave the __ init__.py files empty, and do:

```
import lib.mod1.mod11
lib.mod1.mod11.mod12()
```

or

```
from lib.mod1.mod11 import mod12
mod12()
```

You may find that the mod1 dir is unnecessary, just have mod12.py in lib.

Answer (score 4):

My solution is put those imports in `__init__.py` of lib:

```
in file: __init__.py
import mod1
```

Then,

```
import lib
lib.mod1
```

would work fine.