# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute V2 (custom module)

Tags: python

I have a file, A.py, it basically looks like this:

```
import Hasher
hh = Hasher.V2.Cached_V2()
```

When running, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./A.py", line 2, in <module>
    hh = Hasher.V2.Cached_V2()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'V2'
```

On disk, the files layout is like this:

```
/A.py
/Hasher/__init__.py
/Hasher/V2.py
```

V2.py contains multiple classes, among them `Cached_V2`. 
What's going on? Why isn't the object visible as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your A.py, use `from Hasher import V2` 
 Basically, when you are just importing 'Hasher' only the **init**.py file gets loaded. 
 
Reference: [Python error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871369/python-error-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute)

Note: In your `Hasher/__init__.py` file, if you import V2 using `from . import V2`, then you can use it by directly calling `Hasher.V2` from A.py

Comment: That was it. I wasn't importing them in __init__.py. I'm importing them with import V2, without the `from` clause. What's the point of using from in this case?