# ImportError while trying to use custom package

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I try to group some scripts into a package, but I am getting ImportErrors all the time. System is Ubuntu 16.04, in an Anaconda environment called tensorflow. I'm using python 3.6.

My file structure is like this (project folder is under the home dir of my user):

```
-- project_folder
---- src
     |-> test.py
     |-> package
         |-> A.py
         |-> B.py
         |-> __init__.py
```

`__init__.py` imports `A.py` and `B.py`:

```
## __init__.py contents
import A
import B
```

In `A.py`, I defined a simple test function that prints a string:

```
## A.py contents
def test():
    print('import works')
```

When I work on my test script `test.py`, I get the autocomplete tools to show me the test function. It looks like this

```
## test.py contents
import package

package.A.test()
```

But when executing it, I get an ImportError when trying to import the package:

> ImportError: No module named 'A'

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to set PYTHONPATH? I tried some solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871369/python-error-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute), but none of them worked.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need relative imports, otherwise the interpreter will search for `A` in all directories in `sys.path`, which contains `../src` among standard folders. That is why you get the import error.

```
## __init__.py contents
from . import A
from . import B
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of the concept of relative imports. Definitely going to catch up with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (import directly your module):

```
## test.py contents
import package.A

package.A.test()
```

As for me, this way is better as you know where your module comes from and you don't need to modify `__init__.py` file.

Or you need to include your modules to `__all__` variable:

```
## __init__.py contents
import A
import B

__all__ = ['A', 'B']
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. Neither of those two. Could you elaborate a bit more on the use of __all__?