# Python referencing submodules from importing root package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

### The Problem:

Supposing I have a directory structure like:

```
root/
    __init__.py
    foo.py
    dir1/
        __init__.py
        bar.py
        dir2/
            __init__.py
            baz.py
```

where the various python files contain some function called `hello_world`.

What I want to be able to do is write something like:

```
import root
root.dir1.foo.hello_world()
root.dir1.dir2.baz.hello_world()
```

Of course, when I do this, I get a `AttributeError: module has no attribute` error. This, I think, is due to the "the __init__.py trap" in the [docs](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-init-py-trap). How do I manipulate the init files such that I can make the above code run?

#### Caveats

- I'd like to avoid deleting the init files because they contain the `__all__` parameter, and thats important for my program.
- I'd also like to avoid writing more than one import statement in the main program, so the solution specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871369/python-error-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute) wont work.
- I'm using Python 3.6

### What I've Tried:

I've tried to get around this by changing the __init__.py files into [namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#native-namespace-packages)). Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. E.g. adding:

```
__path__ = __import__('pkgutil').extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

to the various init files doesn't change anything. Similarly, setting the `__path__` attribute directly doesn't solve the problem. E.g. in each init file setting `__path__ = ['<string name of child dir>']` doesn't resolve the error.

This is a bit mysterious to me, since the `__path__` is supposed to tell python where to look for submodules, and the init files are supposed to be run sequentially, so why cant it figure out where things are?

#### Notes:

This issue seems to be described in the docs [here](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-submodules-are-added-to-the-package-namespace-trap)

Answer (score 1):

One solution was to put a `from . import *` after defining the `__all__` property in each init file. E.g. in the init in dir1 put:

```
__all__ = ['foo', 'dir2']
from . import *
```

This solves the use case, but it seems like the wrong way. Open for better answers.