# In Python, how to import all modules from a library in one line?

Tags: python, import, module, package, python-import

The following code works:

```
import torch
import pytorch_lightning   as torchl
import pytorch_forecasting as torchf 
from pytorch_forecasting.data.examples import get_stallion_data
x = torchf.data.examples.get_stallion_data()
print(x)
```

However, if I remove the 4th line, I get an error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pytorch_forecasting.data' has no attribute 'examples'
```

It is tedious and ugly to devote many lines just for loading several modules from one library, like:

```
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import EarlyStopping, LearningRateMonitor
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import TensorBoardLogger
from pytorch_forecasting import Baseline, TemporalFusionTransformer, TimeSeriesDataSet
from pytorch_forecasting.data import GroupNormalizer
from pytorch_forecasting.metrics import SMAPE, PoissonLoss, QuantileLoss
from pytorch_forecasting.models.temporal_fusion_transformer.tuning import optimize_hyperparameters
from pytorch_forecasting.data.examples import get_stallion_data
```

Is there a way to import all these modules using just one line, and then later use them as:

```
x=torchf.bla.bla.bla.bla(parameters)
```

I prefer this way also because there is less danger of name conflicts: calling `x=library1.module(); y=library2.module();` avoids name clashes, unlike `from library1 import *; from library2 import *; x=module(); y=module();`.

Comment: Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

To import everything from a package you can just do `import pytorch_lightning` and it will import all modules and files inside the package. Then you can use it as `x = pytorch_lightning.callbacks.EarlyStopping()`.

The drawback is that you are loading files and modules(and packages that they import consecutively) that you do not necessarily require which increases the import time.

Comment: in addition You can do this `import pytorch_lightning as sth` wher `sth` is any name you prefer but it can be shorter for example `pylight` and then use that for example `pylight.sth.sth()`. Also it will import the whole package anyways if importing something specific in other words it won't increase import time because it still runs the whole file it just keeps the name space a bit more organized so that is not a drawback

Comment: I already tried that, and it doesn't work: try deleting the 4th line above and run the script.

Comment: Would you care to finish this question, please?

Comment: I too was unsuccessful to import it and have submitted it as an issue to pytorch_forecasting Github repo.

Comment: @Leo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871369/python-error-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute This was the response to the issue, which makes sense.